# how to add mocha jstestdriver to webstorm

Tags: mocha.js, webstorm, js-test-driver

I'd like to use the built-in JsTestDriver functionality and code coverage support of the WebStorm IDE.  However, I use mocha instead of Jasmine.

How can I configure webstorm to recognize mocha, or use a mocha plugin?

I did find this piece of code to create a mocha jstestdriver adapater on the web, but not sure how and where to add it to webstorm...

```
/**
 * Mocha JsTestDriver Adapter.
 * @author jan@prachar.eu (Jan Prachar)
 */
(function(){

    /**
     * Our mocha setup
     */
    var setup = mocha.setup;
    var mochaOptions = {};

    mocha.setup = function (opts) {
        if ('string' === typeof opts) {
            mochaOptions.ui = opts;
        } else {
            mochaOptions = opts;
        }

        setup.call(mocha, mochaOptions);
    };

    var getReporter = function (onTestDone, onComplete) {
        var Base = mocha.reporters.Base;
        var Reporter = function (runner) {
            var self = this;

            Base.call(this, runner);
            this.onTestDone = onTestDone;
            this.onComplete = onComplete;

            this.reset = function () {
                jstestdriver.console.log_ = [];
            };

            this.reset();

            runner.on('start', function () {
            });

            runner.on('suite', function (suite) {
            });

            runner.on('suite end', function (suite) {
            });

            runner.on('test', function (test) {
                self.reset();
            });

            runner.on('pending', function () {
            });

            runner.on('pass', function (test) {
                self.onTestDone(new jstestdriver.TestResult(
                    test.parent.fullTitle(),
                    test.title,
                    'passed',
                    '',
                    '',
                    test.duration
                ));
            });

            runner.on('fail', function (test, err) {
                var message = {
                    message: err.message,
                    name: '',
                    stack: err.stack
                };
                self.onTestDone(new jstestdriver.TestResult(
                    test.parent.fullTitle(),
                    test.title,
                    'failed',
                    jstestdriver.angular.toJson([message]),
                    '',
                    test.duration
                ));
            });

            runner.on('end', function () {
                self.onComplete();
            });
        };

        // Inherit from Base.prototype
        Reporter.prototype.__proto__ = Base.prototype;

        return Reporter;
    };

    var MOCHA_TYPE = 'mocha test case';
    TestCase('Mocha Adapter Tests', null, MOCHA_TYPE);

    jstestdriver.pluginRegistrar.register({

        name: 'mocha',

        getTestRunsConfigurationFor: function (testCaseInfos, expressions, testRunsConfiguration) {
            for (var i = 0; i < testCaseInfos.length; i++) {
                if (testCaseInfos[i].getType() === MOCHA_TYPE) {
                    testRunsConfiguration.push(new jstestdriver.TestRunConfiguration(testCaseInfos[i], []));
                }
            }
        },

        runTestConfiguration: function (config, onTestDone, onComplete) {
            if (config.getTestCaseInfo().getType() !== MOCHA_TYPE) return false;

            mochaOptions.reporter = getReporter(onTestDone, onComplete);
            mocha.setup(mochaOptions);
            mocha.run();
            return true;
        },

        onTestsFinish: function () {

        }

    });

})();
```

Comment: `mocha.reporters.base` must be renamed to `Mocha.reporters.Base`, that it's not added to webstorm, it goes inside the `load:` directive inside jstd file

Answer (score 0):

- Does this `Mocha Adapter` really work?
- Were you able to test it from the command?

I would imagine that it would be configured similar to how the `jasmineAdapter.js` is configured below.

```
server: http://<localhost>:4224

load: 
  - tools/Jasmine/jasmine.js
  - tools/Jasmine/jasmineAdapter.js
  - lib/require.js
  - src/*.js

test:   
  - specs/*.js
```